# Rails update method not working: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template items/update...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

The following is my update method in the `items_controller`:

```
def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
      flash[:success] = "Item updated"
      redirect_to edit_item_path(@item)
    else
      render edit_item_path(@item)
    end
  end
```

The `@item` seems to be loaded successfully in the logs, after which `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms` occurs:

```
Item Load (6.7ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = ? ORDER BY "items"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template items/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
 * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
 * " # app route # "
 * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
 ):
 actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
 actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
 actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in    `find_template'
 etc.
```

It seems that `@item.update_attributes(item_params)` might not be doing anything. Any clue how to fix this ?

Comment: Please update your post with complete log.

Answer (score 0):

This should be following:

```
def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
      flash[:success] = "Item updated"
      redirect_to edit_item_path(@item)
    else
      render :edit  # this line should be changed
    end
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything, still get the same error.

Comment: may I see your server log?

Comment: It looks like the `Item.find` is not working, i updated the quesiton.